# Using MERGE for delete and insert in oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

Instead of update my DBA asked me to delete and then insert the values back into the table for performance . I need to use merge here. 
I have not worked on merge before . How do I go ahead and do this? given below are the delete and the insert queries. can merge used for delete and insert alone without any update ?

```
 DELETE FROM hist_tab1 hist
     WHERE hist.tranid IN (SELECT t.tranid
                                    FROM transaction_tab t
                                   WHERE t.tran_status =
                                            'Posted');

 INSERT INTO hist_tab1 (tranid,
    tranamt,
    date,
    post_date,
    isvalid,
    salescode)
   (SELECT tnr.tranid,
           tranamt,
           date,
           post_date,
           isvalid,
          salescode
    FROM tab1 tnr,
          (SELECT tranid
           FROM transaction_tab t
           WHERE t.tran_statu IN ('Posted','Verified')) tt
    WHERE tnr.tranid = tt.transid);
```

Comment: merge is not needed here. when you want to delete some rows and insert some rows , merge is useful. but here you want to delete rows based on transid ( which can be done using merge) ,but you want to insert new rows again based on transid ( here the match is found so only delete will happen, no insert)

Comment: _"Instead of update my DBA asked me to delete and then insert the values back into the table for performance"_ Out of curiosity, what details gave your DBA explaining than _updates_ are slower that _delete then insert_ in that case ? Naively, I would have think of the opposite as that way you touch every index twice.

Comment: kindly share the original update statement

Answer (score 0):

Delete works with update. but it will only delete the rows that are changed by target table and meets the where clause. 
else you can use the some dummy column and try to update and put the delete clause below that.

e.g.

```
Merge into hist_tab1 src using 
((SELECT tnr.tranid,
           tranamt,
           date,
           post_date,
           isvalid,
          salescode
    FROM tab1 tnr,
          (SELECT tranid
           FROM transaction_tab t
           WHERE t.tran_statu IN ('Posted','Verified')) tt
on tnr.tranid = src.transid
when matched then update src.dummy = tt.dummy
delete where tt.tranid IN (SELECT t.tranid
                                    FROM transaction_tab t
                                   WHERE t.tran_status =
                                            'Posted')
when not matched INSERT (src.tranid,
    src.tranamt,
    src.date,
    src.post_date,
    src.isvalid)
values
(trg.tranid,
    trg.tranamt,
    trg.date,
    trg.post_date,
    trg.isvalid
)
```

)
    salescode)